# How to apply filters for more than one domain (Google Analytics)

Tags: google, analytics, spam, referrer

I have about 20 filters for my website to avoid referal spam such as site8.free-floating-buttons.com.

I have more than one website though.
Do I really have to create all these filters for every website, or can I copy og synchronize them somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can accomplish this on different ways:

- if you copy your profile, where the filters are applied, all filters are copied with it
- [this basic addon](http://www.analyticsedge.com/downloads/AnalyticsEdgeBasicInstaller.exe) by analytics edge [does the job too](http://www.analyticsedge.com/2015/02/copy-google-analytics-filters/) (and some other useful things)
- [this greasemonkey script](http://www.roirevolution.com/blog/2009/08/copy_filters_in_google_analytics/) does the job exactly as you described it